# Bulma - why all columns are on one line?

Tags: css, vue.js, frameworks, bulma

I use Bulma with VueJS when I use `v-for`, all columns are on one line, I tried to add`is-4`, then the column width changes but they are still on one line

```
<div class='columns'>
<div class='column' 
v-for='item in weatherData.list' 
v-bind:key='item.data'>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-4by3">
      <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
     </figure>
    </div>
   <div class="card-content">
               ...
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Can anyone explain to me how it works?

Thanks!

EDIT

html output : https://jsfiddle.net/6rfo3dvL/2/

Comment: Could you provide the outputted HTML? This is what I get from your code --> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/6rfo3dvL/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6rfo3dvL/2/

Comment: You just need to add `is-multiline` to your `columns` container. I've added an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want columns to wrap you need to add the `.is-multiline` modifier to the `.columns` class. [More information here](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/#multiline)

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/6rfo3dvL/3/)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='columns is-multiline'>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column is-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Damn, awesome. Thanks!